# Extend android View class and affect all sub classes

Tags: java, android, oop, view

I need to extends View class in Android in order to override couple of methods.

```
public class ExtendedView extends View {

    public ExtendedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && getParent() != null) 
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

     ...
}
```

There are couple of view type in android which derive from `View` such as ImageView and etc.

They do not access to overridden methods in `ExtendedView` class.

One solution is creating extended classes for all of them such as :

```
public class ExtendedImageView extends ImageView
```

And override the methods.

But is there any better solution to avoid such a code redundancy?

Comment: What type of View you want to create. Is it `ImageView` with some special property, or a `View` with special property.

Comment: @GauravGupta I think that the question is clear.  The OP wants to override methods in a base class which are inherited by all subclasses of the base.

Comment: There are couple of view type that need to be affected such as ImageView, MapView, WebView and etc. I have to write the same overridden methods as I wrote in View class.

Comment: I feel the solution you suggest is good solution. For code redundancy you can centralize the code and pass essential params to centralized code.

Comment: You say you want to override a "couple" of methods, but only show `onTouchEvent`.  For that one, I would recommend using `setOnTouchListener()` instead of overriding.  Perhaps the other method also has a similar listener you can set?

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseActivity implementing onTouchEventListener (or something like that, dont remember), then when you have a view which requires to handle it, just setOnTouchListener(this)

Of course, make your activities extend BaseActivity

Regards

Comment: onTouchEvent was just a sample method. That is not what I exactly asked in the question. Thank you for your answer bdw.

Comment: Then yes, you will have to be redundant. Also, making a class that extends from View doesnt make ImageView or MapView to inherit that methods, so you would have to override everyone anyways

Answer (score 0):

As per me this is simple and decent way. 
Here, your code is centralized and one common implementation is given which all intended `ExtendedView` classes will use.

```
class MyImplementation
{
 public boolean methodA(View v, MotionEvent event)
 {
  boolean someBoolean = false;
  // some impl of your spl method.
  if(v instanceOf ExtendedImageView)
   {
     // ImageView called this method.
   }

 }
 return someBoolean;
}
```

Image View implementation

```
public class ExtendedImageView extends ImageView{
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
     {
       MyImplementaion a  = new MyImplemenation();
       boolean b = a.methodA(this, event);
       return b;
     }
}
```

For Some other View

```
public class ExtendedMapView extends MapView{

       public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)
       {
        MyImplementaion a  = new MyImplemenation();
        boolean b = a.methodA(this, event);
        return b;
       }
}
```

Comment: What about **ExtendedView extends View**? not sure if you understood my problem, but thanks for your effort.

Comment: `ExtendedView extends View` will lead to separate branch. That way you will not be able to add special operation to ImageView.

Comment: What I need are the methods that I can override such as onTouchEvent. I can not do that in MyImplementation class.

Comment: Here `someViewMethod` represent method that you want to over ride. Since 2,3 classes have same implementation of `someViewMethod` so i made another class that will contain the common implementation, So that, common code will be written once and can be used by different methods by calling it.

See my edit